# how to create hibernate criteria with group by clause?

Tags: hibernate, group-by, criteria

I need to create criteria analogous to

```
select obj, obj.prop.id from Object1 obj group by obj.prop.id
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example from the reference http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.rowCount() )
        .add( Projections.avg("weight") )
        .add( Projections.max("weight") )
        .add( Projections.groupProperty("color") )
    )
    .list();
```